# Approximating a Compact set by approximating its distance function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, semicontinuous-functions, hausdorff-distance, set-valued-analysis

Let $\emptyset\neq K\subset Y$ be a closed subset of a compact metric space $(X,d)$ such that $K$ has at-least two points and such that
$$
d(Y,K):=\sup_{y\in Y}\,\inf_{k\in K}\,d(k,y)=:r>0.
$$
Define $d_K(x):=\inf_{z\in K}\, d(x,z)$ and let $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be lower semi-continuous and such that
$$
\max_{x\in X}\, \big|f(x)-d_K(x)\big|<r/2.
$$

Define the levelset $K_f:=\{x\in X:\, f(x)\leq r/2\}$ and suppose that $K_f\neq \emptyset$ (e.g. by assuming that $f^{-1}[\{0\}]\neq \emptyset$).

Is it true that $K_f\subseteq Y$?  Moreover, is the Hausdorff distance between $K_f$ and $K$ is at-most $r$?

Comment: Did you mean $K \subseteq K_f$ instead of $K_f \subseteq K$? Also, $K^r$ could easily have a big hole in the middle of it, which will prevent $K_f$ and $K^r$ from being close in general. For example, if $K$ is a closed radius $10$ disc in, say, the closed radius $11$ disc in $\Bbb{R}^2$, and $r = 1$, then $K^r$ will be an annulus, which will necessarily be very different ($9$ in the Hausdorff distance) from the lower level set $K^f$ where $f = d_K$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Not example by I simplified the setting somewhat.  The new version allows us to bypass problems of holes and such I believe.

Comment: I think you mean $\sup_{y \in Y} \inf_{k \in K} d(k, y) =: r > 0$, as what you have is equal to $0$, since $K \subseteq Y$.

Comment: It's looking better. You should probably define $K_r$. Is this just the closure of the set of points of distance at most $r$ from $K$? Or are we defining it like $K^r$ from the previous version (which invites problems with holes once again)?

Comment: @TheoBendit Woops in the current iteration I am forgetting about $K_r$ ($K^r$) and only considering the Hausdorff distance between $K_f$ and $K$.  My hope is that $K_f$ will be the closed $r$-thickening of $K$.

Comment: Looks good now (+1). I'll think about an answer.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for helping me figure out how to pose the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it true that $K_f\subseteq Y$?

No, not necessarily. Take, for example, take $X$ to be $2B_{\Bbb{R}^2}$, the radius $2$ closed unit disc in $\Bbb{R}^2$, and $K = B_{\Bbb{R}^2}$. Further, let
$$Y = K \cup \{(2, 0)\}.$$
Then $r = 1$. If $f = d_K$, then $K_f = \frac{3}{2}B_{\Bbb{R}^2}$, which is not a subset of $Y$.

> Moreover, is the Hausdorff distance between $K_f$ and $K$ is at-most $r$?

Yes! For $\varepsilon \ge 0$, define,
$$K_{\varepsilon} = \operatorname{cl}\left\{x \in X : d_K(x) = \inf_{k \in K} d(x, k) \le \varepsilon\right\}.$$
Then, I claim that
$$K = K_0 \subseteq K_f \subseteq K_r.$$
The first equality comes from the fact that $K$ is closed in $X$. As for the two inequalities, first note that
$$|f(x) - d_K(x)| < \frac{r}{2} \implies d_K(x) < f(x) + \frac{r}{2},$$
for all $x \in X$. So, if $f(x) \le \frac{r}{2}$, we have $d_K(x) < r$, and $x \in K_r$.

On the other hand, if $x \in K$, then $d_K(x) = 0$, so
$$|f(x) - 0| < \frac{r}{2} \implies f(x) < \frac{r}{2},$$
which implies $x \in K_f$.

Now, since $K \subseteq K_f$, the Hausdorff distance between the sets is given by
$$d_H(K, K_f) = \sup_{x \in K_f} \inf_{y \in K} d(x, y) = \sup_{x \in K_f} d_K(x).$$
This is at most $r$, since $K_f \subseteq K_r$.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer Theo.  If you're interested, I posed a follow-up question:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426045/conditions-ensuring-that-a-compact-set-can-be-approximated-by-approximating-its
looking for general conditions on $K$ and $Y$ guaranteeing that $K_f\subseteq Y$.

Comment: @A_K I don't think you'll get anything interesting. To say $Y \supsetneq K$ is distance $r$ from $X$ is to say that it lies somewhere between $K_r$ and $K \cup \{x\}$ for some $x$ where $d_K(x) = r$ (compactness is important here). The extent to which this looks like $K_f$ depends on $f$ and $Y$. It just means that $f$ is lesser around $Y$, and greater not around $Y$, roughly speaking. Anyway, good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight.  It really helped and thanks for the answer to the above question; it was great! :)

Comment: @A_K No worries! Glad I could help.

Comment: @Theo_Bendit If $K$ is geodesically convex, then this would work no?